# Unable to solve a coupled ODE system

Tags: differential-equations

I am unable to solve this coupled system of non-linear ODEs. Mathematica returns the same thing entered.
I'm fairly new to Mathematica. Please let me know if there is a typo, or some limitation is there in Mathematica because of which the solution cannot be reached. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
    DSolve[{D[v[r], r] == (q (-v[r]^3 + (r^-q (r^q \[Gamma] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(M\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[\[Beta], 0]
           v[r]^4 - 
         r (\[Gamma] Subscript[\[Beta], 0] + Subscript[\[Gamma], 
            m]) \[CapitalLambda][
           s[r] (-(r^-q/v[r]))^(-1 + \[Gamma])]))/(
      r^q Subscript[\[Gamma], m] (-(r^-q/v[r]))^Subscript[\[Gamma], 
        m] + \[Gamma] Subscript[\[Beta], 
        0] (r^q s[r] (-(r^-q/v[r]))^\[Gamma] + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(M\), \(0\), \(2\)]\ \(v[r]\)\)))))/(r v[r]^2), 
  D[s[r], r] == 
   q r^q \[Gamma] (-(r^-q/v[r]))^(
    3 - \[Gamma]) \[CapitalLambda][
     s[r] (-(r^-q/v[r]))^(-1 + \[Gamma])]  }, {v[r], s[r]}, r]
```

Comment: Solving a nonlinear ODE with DSolve in a lot of cases impossible. I would recommend you to use NDSolve rather than DSolve and give the system initial conditions also all values need to be defined with a numerical value.

Comment: Also, `Λ[s[r] (-(r^-q/v[r]))^(-1 + γ)]` appears to be an undefined function.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that may help you to formulate your problem in the format of `Mathematica` language:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[12];
L = 4;   (*number of vars*)
TT = 10;  (*time horizon of the dynamic solution*)
X0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, L];   (*initial conditions*)
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {L,L}];  (*matrix of coeffs of non-linear equations*)
variables = Table[Unique["x"], {L}]; (*vars notation*)
X[t_] = #[t] & /@ variables;   (*vars defined as functions*)
system = X'[t] == A.X[t];  (*the system to solve*)
constraints = X[0] == X0;  (*initial conditions*)
sol = X[t] /. NDSolve[{system, constraints}, variables, {t, 0, TT}]
Plot[sol, {t, 0, TT}]
```

generates:

[image]

If you use `Manipulate`, you will be able to generate different initial conditions and coefficient matrices automatically:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Manipulate[
SeedRandom[12];
X0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, neq]; 
AA = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {neq, neq}];
variables = Table[Unique["x"], {neq}];
X[t_] = #[t] & /@ variables;  
system = X'[t] == AA.X[t]; 
constraints = X[0] == X0;
sol = X[t] /.NDSolve[{system, constraints}, variables, {t, 0, ntime}];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, ntime}],
{{neq, 5, "number of equations: "}, 4, 20, 1},
{{ntime, 5, "time horizon: "}, 1, 30, 5}
]
```

generates:

[image]